# Как изменить текущий рабочий каталог на C?

Tags: c

есть папка, в ней находится код C, но мне нужно выполнять действия, как если бы этот файл находился в папке Python, т.е. C:\Python39\include
Перемещать файл не выход из ситуации, следовательно нужно сменить рабочий каталог на нужный мне, в python для этого есть функция chdir, у меня вопрос, есть ли что-то похожее в языке C?

Comment: Вы будете удивлены, но именно из C-*nix и пошел [chdir](https://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir) (лет уже 50 как) по всем остальным языкам

Comment: Странно, но я нигде не нашел ни использования этой команды, ни ее синтаксиса, как она должна прописываться?

Comment: Странно, я же ссылку на manpage привел... Например, `#include <unistd.h> .... chdir("/tmp"); ...` сменит текущий каталог на `/tmp`

Comment: А, извиняюсь, не заметил, да, синтаксис решен, но такое впечатление, что каталог не меняется или я что-то неправильно делаю

Comment: Как бы вам код привести

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <C:\\Python39\\include\\Python.h>

int main() {
  chdir("C:\\Python39\\include");
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("print('Hello!')");
  Py_Finalize();
}

Comment: Я не пишу в винде

Comment: [_chdir](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/chdir-wchdir?view=msvc-160) не забудьте проверить возвращаемое значение!

Comment: У вас не *компилируется* или не *выполняется*?

Comment: А текущий ДИСК у вас `С:`?

Comment: не компилируется

Comment: Да, диск используется C

Answer (score 0):

[Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1226318/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c/1226333#comment2147483_1226318) проблема не со сменой каталога, а с линковкой.

```
gcc -shared -o app.exe app.c -IC:\Python39\include -LC:\Python39 -LC:\Python39\DLLs -lpython3

-I путь к инклуду
-L путь к dll
-l имя дллки
```

Comment: После такой команды: gcc -shared -o app.exe app.c -IC:\Python39\include -LC:\Python39\libs -lpython39

Comment: Лезет такая ошибка: In file included from C:\Python39\include/Python.h:85,
                 from app.c:2:
C:\Python39\include/pytime.h:123:59: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
  123 | PyAPI_FUNC(int) _PyTime_FromTimeval(_PyTime_t *tp, struct timeval *tv);
      |                                                           ^~~~~~~
C:\Python39\include/pytime.h:130:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration

Comment: 130 |     struct timeval *tv,
      |            ^~~~~~~
C:\Python39\include/pytime.h:135:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration  135 |     struct timeval *tv,
      |            ^~~~~~~c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:

Comment: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccl8R5pa.o:app.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccl8R5pa.o:app.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `_imp__PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccl8R5pa.o:app.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Finalize'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: В винде есть программа python3.9-config ? попробуй получить все флаги python3.9-config --cflags
`-I/usr/include/python3.9 -I/usr/include/python3.9  -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fno-semantic-interposition -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall`

Comment: попробуй вот так, изменил в ответе

Comment: Странно, точно такая же ошибка

Comment: @Andrei эх тяжело без pkgconfig) а питон то у Вас небось на msvc собран... А попробуйте питон пересобрать на mingw-gcc

Comment: Возможно, а как это делать?

Comment: @Andrei или ситон собрать на msvc..  Винды нет под рукой с повторить это все...